# CSS body width 100 percent

Tags: css

I am new to CSS and I have a problem understanding how the following piece of code works:

```
body {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
```

I understand that when you specify `width: 100%`.

The element's total width will be 100% of it's containing block. The body containing block is html, but **my question is what is the size of the html?**

**The size of the html depends of the user monitor resolution?**

If this is the case then when I create a site and I user percent all the elements size will vary depending on the monitor resolution?

I am not sure if I fully understand the concept so any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You can define all the html elements size includint html element, by default html elements and body will caught all the screen size with  a padding or margin. Investigate it creating simple html pages that only have a body and look for the structure on google chrome inspector

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The HTML element is effectively the `viewport` (browser window visible area) the `body` element is the actual content of the page.

[More on this:](http://phrogz.net/css/htmlvsbody.html)

> 1. The html and body elements are distinct block-level entities, in a parent/child relationship.
> 2. The html element's height and width are controlled by the browser window.
> 3. It is the html element which has (by default) overflow:auto, causing scrollbars to appear when needed.
> 4. The body element is (by default) position:static, which means that positioned children of it are positioned relative to the html
>      element's coordinate system.
> 5. In almost all modern browsers, the built-in offset from the edge of the page is applied through a margin on the body element, not padding
>      on the html element.

### [HTML](http://mdn.beonex.com/en/HTML/Element/html.html)

> The HTML root element (`<html>`) represents the root of an HTML or XHTML
>   document. All other elements must be descendants of this element.

### [Body](http://mdn.beonex.com/en/HTML/Element/body.html)

> The HTML Body (`<body>`) element represents the main content of an HTML
>   document. There is only one  element in a document.

Answer (score 2):

**A percentage based value is always based on the object outside of it (it's parent).**

**To answer your question:** In HTML you can't add any content, HTML is the parent of `head` and `body`. `body` is the holder for actual content.

To explain width percentages in CSS, I give you this example:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="grandparent" style="width:90%;">
            <div id="parent" style="width:80%;">
                <div id="child" style="width:70%;">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
<html>
```

**Let's pretend we're looking on a screen that is 500 pixels (px) wide.**

`body` is the parent of the grandparent, as the div `grandparent` is inside of `body`; it holds the same width as the document, as that's the standard CSS value. (which is 500px as I mentioned in this example).

- `grandparent` has 90% width of `body` **(450px)**
- `parent` has 80% width of `grandparent` **(360px)**
- `child` has 70% the width of `parent` **(252 px)**