# The purpose of 100 percent width for body

Tags: html, css

What is the possible purpose of `width: 100%` for body and html elements?

Sometimes I could see something like this reset-like snippet on live websites, as well at StackOverflow answers:

```
html, body
{
  width:  100%; /* ? */
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
```

The question may sound silly, but it really bother me. I don't like the situation in which I have some "black magic" in the root elements of HTML-document. This makes me feel that I don't understand the fundamental outlines of what I'm doing.

Comment: I thinks it is a cross platform css rule that resets the body and html elements to a standard format. If i remember correctly, some browsers react differently if these rules are not set.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS body width 100 percent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23560084/css-body-width-100-percent)

Comment: As Nitin said it's called a "reset" it is there just to make sure your style looks as expected. Most if the time it's not needed but better safe than sorry.

Comment: @Tha'erAl-Ajlouni No, I don't think these questions are identical or even closely related. Simply saying, I want to understand why some developers adds "width: 100%" to their sites, even if it really doesn't change anything.

Comment: It's not necessary. There is no situation where that particular combination on it's own requires `width:100%`. However, there are situations where it might be necessary in combination with other CSS. For example, If you additionally had `body { position:absolute; }` or `html { display:table; }` then you probably would want to set the width to 100%. If you see it on its own, the likelihood is that the author didn't know what they were doing and just cargo-cult copied it from somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

This styles are added just to ensure `html` and `body` occupy 100% width of your screen. Just for the case if something is overriding defaults (e.g. in another CSS file). But I've never seen a browser which has another defaults then this.

If you set another value it will occupy more or less then 100%.

```css
html, body {
  width: 125%;
}
```

```html
In this case body will occupy 125% * 125% = 156.25% of screen width because of 125% body width relative to 125% html
```

Comment: Well yes. But the body element is 100% width by default. OPs question is _why would it be necessary to set it to 100%_?

Comment: Just in case if something is overriding defaults. Never seen a browser which has another defaults then this.